# file_put_contents: Failed to open stream, no such file or directory

Tags: php, dompdf

I am trying to use dompdf to save a form to an easily-readable .pdf file, and my processing script is below. I am receiving the error `Warning: file_put_contents(/files/grantapps/NAME0.pdf) [function.file-put-contents]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/username/public_html/subdir/apps/dompdf/filename.php on line 39`. (Line 39 is the final line in my full script.) I don't know how to resolve this issue.

`allow_url_fopen` is on, and I have tried all kinds of file paths, including the full directory (`/home/username/public_html/subdir/files/grantapps/`) and what's in the code below, but nothing worked.

```
require_once("dompdf_config.inc.php");
date_default_timezone_set('America/Detroit');

$html = 'code and whatnot is here';

$name = str_replace(" ", "", $_POST['form2name']);
$i = 0;
$dompdf = new DOMPDF();
$dompdf->load_html($html);
$dompdf->render();
while(file_exists("files/grantapps/" . $name . $i . ".pdf")) {
    $i++;
}
file_put_contents("files/grantapps/" . $name . $i . ".pdf", $dompdf->output());
```

Comment: A user may submit the form multiple times, and, since I'm using their name as the file name, I wanted it to just append a number to the end and save each file with a new file name rather than overwriting the existing file.

Comment: why not use $dompdf->stream("files/grantapps/" . $name . $i . ".pdf");

Comment: The `stream()` function causes a download of the file and only accepts a file name as a parameter. I want to save the file on the web server, and other locations said `file_put_contents()` is the way to do it.

Comment: For anyone having the same error message and came to this thread, in my case the issue was due to an **invalid file name** (it contained a `/`)

Answer (score 44, accepted):

There is definitly a problem with the destination folder path.

Your above error message says, it wants to put the contents to a file in the directory `/files/grantapps/`, which would be beyond your `vhost`, but somewhere in the system (see the leading absolute slash )

You should double check:

- Is the directory `/home/username/public_html/files/grantapps/` really present.
- Contains your loop and your file_put_contents-Statement the absolute path `/home/username/public_html/files/grantapps/`

Comment: I am the world's biggest idiot. I had done everything *except* creating the `/grantapps/` directory. Creating that and going back to the full link worked. Sorry, thank you so much!

Comment: I have the same problem and all my paths are perfectly set up, it just throws the same error.

Comment: The important part for me was the use of the **absolute** path, I was using `~/`.

Comment: For anyone having the same error message and came to this thread, in my case the issue was due to an **invalid file name** (it contained a `/`)

Comment: In my case the path and target file both existed, but php didn't have permission to write to it (which chmod fixed) :-/

Answer (score 8):

I was also stuck on the same kind of problem and I followed the simple steps below.

Just get the exact url of the file to which you want to copy, for example:

```
http://www.test.com/test.txt (file to copy)
```

Then pass the exact **absolute folder path with filename** where you do want to write that file.

1. If you are on a Windows machine then
   `d:/xampp/htdocs/upload/test.txt`
2. If you are on a Linux machine then
   `/var/www/html/upload/test.txt`

You can get the document root with the PHP function `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`.