# php file_put_contents not creating file from url

Tags: php, rest

I'm working with two different APIs trying to transfer documents from one services to another. So far, the API has been kind of clunky to work with, but I was getting it to work, until now with the documents problem. Here is what I have to do:
 
1. I need to get the url of the document from the one service (which I have done).
 
2. Download it to my own servers to a folder called filesToUpload (which I have created).
3. Transfer it to the other services (which I have done with a document already on my servers.)
So as you can see, the problem isn't transferring it to the other service, the real problem is downloading it to my own servers. Here is what I have tried:(the $doc['url'] is the response from the one server, and I have confirmed that the url supplied is an existent document)

```
$fileToPost = str_replace(" ", "+", $doc["url"]);
$fileName = strchr($fileToPost, "-");
$fileName = substr($fileName, 1);
file_put_contents("/api/ricochet-clean/filesToUpload/$fileName", fopen($fileToPost, 'r'));
```

Here is my error message:

```
file_put_contents(/api/ricochet-clean/filesToUpload/uploaded-leads.s3.amazonaws.com/219-2018-06-10-10-19-04-Assign6.docx): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in <b>/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/SoftwareAPIs/api/ricochet-clean/index.php</b> on line <b>191</b><br />
```

In the `file_put_contents()` function call, I have tried the `/api/ricochet-clean/filesToUpload/$fileName` absolute path and I have also tried a relative path of `filesToUpload/$fileName`.
I saw this question: [file_put_contents: Failed to open stream, no such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14783592/file-put-contents-failed-to-open-stream-no-such-file-or-directory)
The answer to this was the developer hadn't created the directory he was trying to download the file to, that isn't my problem because I've confirmed I created the directory AND it is spelled the same both places.

What am I missing here?

Comment: The path to directory/file might be wrong. Try like this: `file_put_contents("./api/ricochet-clean/filesToUpload/$fileName", fopen($fileToPost, 'r'));` Or you can use absolute path instead of relative.

Comment: @LovepreetSingh I'm getting the same error

Comment: Are you sure that file exists with `$filename`?

Comment: @LovepreetSingh that's the thing...I'm creating the file in that line. No, that file doesn't exist yet, but it should automatically create it if it doesn't exist. At least that's what the php docs say here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php

Comment: Then it should be the issue with path you have given.

Answer (score 0):

The file you wish to write is

`/api/ricochet-clean/filesToUpload/$fileName`

but the file being written is

`/api/ricochet-clean/filesToUpload/uploaded-leads.s3.amazonaws.com/219-2018-06-10-10-19-04-Assign6.docx`

Assuming the directory `uploaded-leads.s3.amazonaws.com` does not exist, you will need to create it, or write code to create it.

The quotation marks you're using here are absolutely fine.

Answer (score -1):

Will you try like this?

file_put_contents("'/api/ricochet-clean/filesToUpload/$fileName'", fopen($fileToPost, 'r'));

Comment: Did u do it correctly? I mean, inside the double quotes, use single quote.

Comment: There is no need here to put quotes in more quotes.