# Laravel file_put_contents() Failed to open stream: No such file or directory after deployment

Tags: laravel

I was working on an API project on local

When I uploaded the project on VPS and I try to open the website in the browser I found this issue

```
file_put_contents(/home/realestateindex/backend.realestateindex.net/rindexfinal/storage/framework/sessions/FJCgAYQNZOwpnBEc0ublubwJiVE5ryMKX1tem6Ew): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

When I tried to call storage:link I faced similar error

I tried these commands and still not working

```
php artisan config:clear
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan config:cache
```

Comment: Please check this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14783592/file-put-contents-failed-to-open-stream-no-such-file-or-directory

Comment: I assume it permissions issue, try to change storage dir perms to `777 ` recursively: `chmod -R 777 storage`